# Web2Py Python ignores currently latest pymongo installed version

Tags: python, pymongo, web2py

**Error:** pydal requires pymongo version >= 3.0, found '2.2.1'

**Pymongo:**

```
import pymongo
pymongo.version
'3.2.2'
```

**Stack of errors:** `<type 'exceptions.RuntimeError'> Failure to connect, tried 5 times: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Applications/web2py.app/Contents/Resources/gluon/packages/dal/pydal/base.py", line 446, in __init__ File "/Applications/web2py.app/Contents/Resources/gluon/packages/dal/pydal/adapters/base.py", line 60, in __call__ File "/Applications/web2py.app/Contents/Resources/gluon/packages/dal/pydal/adapters/mongo.py", line 91, in __init__ Exception: pydal requires pymongo version >= 3.0, found '2.2.1'`

**Environment:** OSX 10.11, Python 2.7.10

I just stared with Python so I need help. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a fix to this issue but I finally move on using the source code version of web2py